# Consulta PostgreSQL sem retorno de dados

Tags: sql, postgresql, data

Veja o seguinte código SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM venda ve WHERE ve.datavenda <= DATE '28/08/2016'
```

No banco tem os seguintes dados:

[image: registro na referida tabela]

A consulta SQL acima não está devolvendo nenhum resultado, porquê? 
Poderiam me ajudar? agradeço desde já!

Comment: nem precisa usa o date o campo ja esta em time stamp 
`SELECT * FROM venda WHERE datavenda <= '2016-08-28'`

Comment: Não, não vejo erro algum! Isso está correto @stderr

Comment: Qual o retorno esperado?

Comment: Posso fazer uma pergunta de curiosidade pessoal? Porque as pessoas escrevem "Postgree"? Eu entendo algumas confusões com o nome, mas nunca entendi essa. Isso não é o nome do produto, apelido, abreviação, nada. O que isso significa?

Comment: @bigown Sei que existe algo próximo do que comentou, mas no momento da pronúncia em inglês, que se escrita em português ficaria próxima de "postgree".

Answer (score 3):

Isso acontece pois campo `datavenda` da tabela `vendas` é do tipo `timestamp`, sua consulta está sendo interpretada da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT * FROM venda ve WHERE ve.datavenda <= '28/08/2016 00:00:00.000000';
```

O que **não inclui** os registros `28/08/2016 02:33:36.372` e `28/08/2016 02:55:46.873`, e explica o comportamento descrito.

Existem duas possíveis soluções para o seu problema:

```
SELECT * FROM venda ve WHERE ve.datavenda <= '28/08/2016 23:59:59.999999';
```

ou

```
SELECT * FROM venda ve WHERE ve.datavenda::date <= '28/08/2016';
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Agradeço, era isso mesmo! Meus mais sinceros agradecimentos!

Answer (score 1):

Altere sua query para;

```
SELECT * FROM venda ve WHERE ve.datavenda::date <= '28/08/2016'
```

Comment: Obrigado! Ajudou bastante!